# For implementing virtualization in a non-ItemsControl, is it better to retrofit ItemContainerGenerator, or implement simple custom generation?

Tags: wpf, panel, itemscontrol, itemcontainergenerator

We're rolling our own special Items-based control/panel combo that isn't based on a subclass of ItemsControl (there are multiple reasons why we can't do this which I won't get into here) but our control does handle thousands and thousands of data items, so we'd like to implement `Visual` virtualization.

What we're wondering is if it makes more sense to try and bang the existing ItemContainerGenerator class into our design or roll our own virtualization method.

On the one hand, ItemContainerGenerator already handles virtualization and is very efficient, and tried-and-true code is almost always preferable to starting from scratch, but on the other, the ICG was designed specificially for use with, and relies on features of the ItemsControl, which again, this control is not.  Plus, that is a *container* generator but in our case, we just need to generate and lay out a specific, known visual that represents the data item.

Now, perhaps I'm over-simplifying things, but all I see is a need to determine which items would be visible in the ViewPort, ensure visual representations of those items are created, measured and arranged, then discard any left-over already-created visuals.  To keep track of it all, it seems a simple item-to-visual mapping scheme is all that is needed, perhaps with a ItemVisual attached property on the DataItem's ViewModel object.  That way when an item is removed/destroyed, we just check if there's an existing visual, and if so, nuke it.

That said, can anyone think of a reason we shouldn't simply roll our own visual virtualization? Again, the ICG does this, but I'm wondering if that's taking a Semi to the store to get eggs.